# Import photos from wesbite to an app

Tags: android, api, photos

I have made an android app for someone else. The app has a gallery option that should show various photos. The person I am giving this app to has no programming knowledge. I would like to have a common place where the person can upload pics and they show automatically in the app and get updated for all the app users. And by "common place" I mean a site like google photos or something. I would not want users to have to authenticate or anything. Whenever they open the app, the photos should get downloaded from the site. Which web service allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think a lot of photo sites would allow you to do this. I've [done it in the past](http://www.akawebdesign.com/2010/04/13/extjs-flickr-and-wordpress/) with Flickr and PHP, so I imagine it could be done using Android/Java.

Having said that, there's likely to be a lot more you need to consider. Photo sites have various terms of service, copyright agreements, and other important things you'll want to tell your client about before blindly deciding on a service just because it allows you to accomplish this task.